# Civ 6 Map editor

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a way to edit maps in Civilization 6?  That is, to create and edit terrain and add resources?   I have looked at the Civilization 6 SDK but can't see a map editor/world builder.   This was in Civilization 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The World Builder is not released yet. There is a way how to use it, though, but it's very buggy. You can look up a tutorial how to still use it [here](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/how-do-you-play-maps-made-with-worldbuilder.613324/).

What I would recomment is using FireTuner to change ingame objects such as terrain or resources. **[You can check here.](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/fire-tuner-and-you-video-version.26206/)**